# Raspberry Pi Noobs Static address config

Tags: networking, raspbian

I have installed Raspbian using Noobs.

I need to set a static ip address.

The config files on my Pi bears not relation the articles I can find on the internet.

Can anyone point me to a good article or advise me of the settings.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/5538

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to get the mac address of the device (eg. [1](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/finding-the-mac-address-of-a-raspberry-pi/)), then assign one using your router ([2](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-assign-static-ip-address-3442670/)). This avoids having to dig through config files as long as you have router admin access!

Comment: +1 I've never really understood the appeal of setting all that using the OS itself... Granted, the router thing isn't always possible, but it is certainly simpler for the majority of people.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address) seems to be pretty detailed and shows exactly what you need to do:

In summary, do:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

TO

```
iface eth0 inet static
```

Add:

```
address <desired_ip>
netmask <run ifconfig -> Mask field>
network <run netstat -> Destination>
broadcast <run ifconfig -> Bcast field>
gateway <run netstat -nr - look for gateway>
```

then

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dhcp/*
sudo reboot
```

To check: ifconfig and make sure you get that ip.

Comment: Sorry it doesnt.  Running the command                                                sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
                                                                                                                                                                                                        The output bears no resemblance to the output shown in the webpage

Comment: What does your output look like?

Comment: Try this: http://sizious.com/2015/08/28/setting-a-static-ip-on-raspberry-pi-on-raspbian-20150505/

Comment: Thanks very much tasasaki. Good link and good to see its not only me having problems. Network scanning still show 2 addresses, 192.168.10.1 and the one I have allocated. SSH can only connect on the address I assigned. Thanks again.